# Recursive callback in lambda?

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, lambda

How to make something like this to work?

```
std::function<void()> infinity=[&]() ->void
{
    QPromise<void>([=](const QPromiseResolve<void>& resolve, const QPromiseReject<void>& reject) {
        QTimer::singleShot(25, [&]() {
            qDebug() << "step into infinity";
            resolve();
        });
    }).then([&]() {
        //infinity();
        QTimer::singleShot(225, [&]() {infinity();});
    });
};

infinity();
```

I keep getting segmentation fault error or timer does not recall the function

Ok so this works, get a reference first then pass by value

```
std::function<void()> infinity=[&infinity]() ->void
{
    QPromise<void>([infinity](const QPromiseResolve<void>& resolve, const QPromiseReject<void>& reject) {
        QTimer::singleShot(25, [resolve](){
            qDebug() << "step into infinity";
            resolve();
        });
    }).then([infinity]() {
        //infinity();
        QTimer::singleShot(225, [infinity]() {infinity();});
    });
};
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you're using `infinity();` in your lambda and when you do, the variable has gone out of scope. Try using `[=]` instead of `[&]`.

Comment: Using [=] will likely result in a memory leak, since the lambda will capture a reference to itself.

Comment: Nah tried also by value still getting seg fault

Comment: You're capturing it by reference twice. Make sure it is captured by value both times.

Comment: I captured everything but &resolve by value still nothing

Comment: @ValentinoMiori I mean this is an interesting question, and I'd like to know the answer. But I have to say it seems like a better plan would have been to make this an actual function, not a lambda.

Comment: Then the segfault has some other reason, other than the recursive call. When you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, where did your debugger say the segfault occured?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding QTimer with Lambda and recursive function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713879/understanding-qtimer-with-lambda-and-recursive-function-call)